# How to step onto/debug imported java code in netbeans

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I have been searching for a long time on how to step through imported code classes in netbeans with no solution.
When debugging or stepping into the code, netbeans does not highlight and stop at the imported code classes being used. This is extremely inconvenient since the code I am working on is complex and stepping through is the only way to fully understand it.

I created a new project with existing sources. I have made sure that under window>debugging>sources I have added my working folders.
I also made sure the sources were added in the "runtime" classpath. 
The compile classpath appears to be empty, I'm not sure whether that has something to do with it.

MORE INFO: In the debugging window while the program is paused, the main method profile from my imported class says it is reading from "Hidden source calls", but it is really just the normal imported code.

Why is this happening? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Folks,

One of the reasons you can get Hidden Source calls is adding in existing packages and java source code at the wrong directory level. You MUST add in the parent directory of the package not the child directory that represent the package name,

example if you have /home/torsi/java/src/torsipackage/com/main.java, you need to add in src, not torsipackage, you will now you made this mistake if you see  listed in the top-level package name for your package.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Well I've not heard the term "Hidden source calls" before but I wonder if you're trying to step into third party code? If you want to step into compiled code it must have source associated I believe. I think it's possible to step into native code because they include the source somehow in the distribution for that exact reason. If you want to step into a library that's been developed by some other private entity you will likely not be afforded that luxury unless it's open source, and even then you may have to retrieve the source first.

Ultimately my point is that there is a difference between a .java file and a .class file. I believe it's possible to reverse engineer .class files but haven't done research on the topic.

If you want to step into code you didn't write odds are you'll need to change your code to work with the imported library or alternatively file a bug report with the developer.

Comment: The code I am trying to step through isn't an imported library, rather a collection of classes. It was developed by a third party, but they supplied the source code. Everything in their code is viewable, the only issue is that the debugger doesn't like it... I even moved these classes to be in the netbeans working folder. Nothing works.

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to need a bit more information to be of help. From your description it sounds like you have a collection of classes that was developed by a third party that you have integrated into your source?

Comment: Was the collection of classes delivered via jar file? if so why aren't you including it as a library? What package are the classes a member of? Or I guess you could just let me know what third party code you're using... Do they have an installation guide? What version of netbeans are you running? https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=129423

Comment: The source code was provided as a zip file, so no jar, just a folder of class files. It is a school related code developed non commercially that I am trying to "fix up". It only references other classes in the folder that were imported as well, so it's pretty independent. I even tried compiling a new project that would put all of the files into a library and imported it. No luck either. It doesn't want to step through that code... I was thinking there might be an issue with the ant code, but I can't tell. The version of netbeans is 8.0.2 for Linux